# Android NDK - why am I getting this assembler error 'internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up'

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk, arm

I am attempting to build the EAS Sonivox midi library from here: https://github.com/android/platform_external_sonivox, because Android 7 (Nougat) no longer allows linking to unsupported libraries. All architectures build OK except for arm, because of the arm assembler code included in the library sources. The project is here: https://github.com/billthefarmer/mididriver. The errors I get are:

```
jni/lib_src/ARM-E_filter_gnu.s: Assembler messages:
jni/lib_src/ARM-E_filter_gnu.s:67: Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up
jni/lib_src/ARM-E_filter_gnu.s:68: Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up
jni/lib_src/ARM-E_filter_gnu.s:71: Error: cannot represent OFFSET_IMM8 relocation in this object file format
jni/lib_src/ARM-E_filter_gnu.s:72: Error: cannot represent OFFSET_IMM8 relocation in this object file format
jni/lib_src/ARM-E_filter_gnu.s:75: Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up
jni/lib_src/ARM-E_filter_gnu.s:76: Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up
jni/lib_src/ARM-E_filter_gnu.s:77: Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up
jni/lib_src/ARM-E_filter_gnu.s:98: Error: cannot represent OFFSET_IMM8 relocation in this object file format
jni/lib_src/ARM-E_filter_gnu.s:101: Error: cannot represent OFFSET_IMM8 relocation in this object file format
jni/lib_src/ARM-E_filter_gnu.s:115: Error: cannot represent OFFSET_IMM8 relocation in this object file format
jni/lib_src/ARM-E_filter_gnu.s:117: Error: cannot represent OFFSET_IMM8 relocation in this object file format
jni/lib_src/ARM-E_filter_gnu.s:123: Error: cannot represent OFFSET_IMM8 relocation in this object file format
jni/lib_src/ARM-E_filter_gnu.s:124: Error: cannot represent OFFSET_IMM8 relocation in this object file format
```

The offending code lines:

```
LDR     pBuffer, [pWTFrame, #m_pAudioBuffer]
LDR     numSamples, [pWTFrame, #m_numSamples]

@load state variables from pFilter structure
LDRSH   z1, [pFilter, #m_z1]
LDRSH   z2, [pFilter, #m_z2]

@load coefficients from pWTFrame structure
LDR     K, [pWTFrame, #m_k]
LDR     b1, [pWTFrame, #m_b1]
LDR     b2, [pWTFrame, #m_b2]
```

and, missing a few dotted through the source file

```
STRH    z1, [pFilter, #m_z1]
STRH    z2, [pFilter, #m_z2]
```

I have done an extensive online search and cannot find anything to shed any light on this, and I am puzzled how Google and others manage to build this library, unless they are using a different toolchain - this library builds OK on a Raspberry Pi. The instructions are all valid arm address modes according to the docs. I have worked around it by commenting out the part of the Android.mk file that conditionally builds the assembly code.

Any light shed on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `m_xxx` symbols can't be relocatable (or otherwise generate relocations). They need to be and absolute and fully resolved at assembly time, so the problem appears to be how they're defined. Looking at the source I'd guess your problem is that they're aren't being defined at all because the assembler symbol `FILTER_ENABLED` isn't set to 1. See `mididriver/jni/lib_src/arm-wt-22k_lib.mak`.

Comment: FILTER_ENABLED is defined in the Android.mk file that the android ndk uses. These m_xxx values are defined as 0 or 2 or similar. The makefile you refer to I assume is used to build an executable for testing.

Comment: If they were defined that way you wouldn't get the errors you've shown.